# $RANDOM in script vs. on command line

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I think I found a really odd bug in Bash's random number generator (`$RANDOM`).

Showing is easier than telling, so here's what happens:

The goal is to get random digits. If I execute this, I get 20 random digits as expected.

```
for i in {1..20}; do echo $((RANDOM % 10)); done
```

But if the `echo` statement is in a script, I get a really odd pattern of digits.

```
$ cat randomtest
#!/bin/bash
echo $((RANDOM % 10))

$ for i in {1..20}; do ./randomtest; done
9
8
8
6
7
5
5
4
4
2
3
1
1
1
0
0
8
9
7
7
```

What in the world is going on?

System information:

- Mac OS X 10.10.2
- GNU Bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (installed via Homebrew)

Comment: Fine here .... have you run it many times?

Comment: Yes, and it gives the same odd skipping downward pattern every time.

Comment: @MiJyn edited to add system information. I'm on Mac OS X, but using GNU Bash via Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I feel silly.

The problem was that `/bin/bash` is OS X's default Bash 3.2. Homebrew installs Bash to `/usr/local/bin/bash`, which is what I'm using in my terminal. If I change the shebang to that, it works as expected.